# Why java TransferQueue cannot "transfer()" after "put()"?

Tags: java, concurrency, queue, freeze, transfer

I've got a very simple code snippet:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TransferQueue<Integer> transferQueue = new LinkedTransferQueue<>();
    System.out.println("Step1");
    transferQueue.put(2);
    System.out.println("Step2");
    transferQueue.transfer(2);
    System.out.println("Step3");
}
```

Run this program, it prints:

```
Step1
Step2
```

And then hangs there. So why "transfer()" function doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained by the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html#transfer(E)) for the `transfer(e)` method.

> More precisely, transfers the specified element immediately if there exists a consumer already waiting to receive it (in `take()` or timed poll), else inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue **and waits until the element is received by a consumer**.

Emphasis added!

In your example, there is no consumer to receive the element, so the `transfer(2)` call blocks forever.

(This is nothing to do with the preceding `put(2)` call.)